# Smartsheet sample project "could not load assembly..." error

Tags: smartsheet-api

Just started to try Smartsheet api and I'm stuck at the very beginning...:) This is the repo I downloaded and tried to run - https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/csharp-read-write-sheet

However, it gave the error "*System.IO.FileNotFoundException
HResult=0x80070002
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Source=
StackTrace:*

" at the very beginning. Plus, there are yellow triangle warning icon next to the References Newtonsoft.Json, NLog and RestSharp - see snapshot below.

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks.

[image]